# Why is it saying the index is out of range?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

It is saying "error, index out of range"

I already tried making it a 0..< that still returns the error. Been looking over the code for 30 minutes can't figure out what I messed up

```
func kidsWithCandies(_ candies: [Int], _ extraCandies: Int) -> [Bool] {
    var greatestCandyNum = 0
    var arrayOfBools = Array<Bool>()
    for kid in candies {
        if candies[kid] > greatestCandyNum {
            greatestCandyNum = candies[kid]
            arrayOfBools.append(false)
        }
    }
    for kid in candies {
        if candies[kid] + extraCandies >= greatestCandyNum{
            arrayOfBools[kid] = true
        }
    }
    for kid in candies {
        if candies[kid] == greatestCandyNum {
            arrayOfBools[kid] = true
        } else if candies[kid] > greatestCandyNum {
            greatestCandyNum = candies[kid]
            arrayOfBools[kid] = true
        }
    }
    return arrayOfBools
}
```

Comment: All `kid in candies` should be `kid in candies.indices`?

Comment: Because actually it's no index.

Answer (score 0):

So the main issue is that you cannot pass the value from the for loop into the index of the array. You can use the enumerate function to generate the index of where you are in the array position.
As seen with:

```
for (index, kid) in candies.enumerated()
```

I also fixed your initial for loop that would not generate a consistent Bool array if your candies array was not ascending. This was done with an else

Also please see that when iterating you can use the "kid" value rather than trying to find it again in the array.

### Disclaimer: There are however much better ways of doing this.

```
func kidsWithCandies(_ candies: [Int], _ extraCandies: Int) -> [Bool] {
    var greatestCandyNum = 0
    var arrayOfBools = Array<Bool>()
    for kid in candies {
        if kid > greatestCandyNum {
            greatestCandyNum = kid
            arrayOfBools.append(false)
        } else {
            arrayOfBools.append(true)
        }
    }
    for (index, kid) in candies.enumerated() {
        if kid + extraCandies >= greatestCandyNum {
            arrayOfBools[index] = true
        }
    }
    for (index, kid) in candies.enumerated() {
        if kid == greatestCandyNum {
            arrayOfBools[index] = true
        } else if kid > greatestCandyNum {
            greatestCandyNum = kid
            arrayOfBools[index] = true
        }
    }
    return arrayOfBools
}
```